# Хранение списка объектов в сущности

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

У меня есть `Entity`, например `Fruits`.
Ее класс:

```
@Entity
class Fruits {
   @Id
   long id;

   List<Apple> apples;
}
```

И класс яблока

```
class Apple {
   String variety;
}
```

`Apple` - обертка над строкой в которой я хочу валидировать данные и возможно еще какие-то действия.

Проблема в том, что `List` в `Entity` не может содержать не `Entity`. Как я могу
хранить строку из `Apple` в базе данных, но в классе `Fruits` хранилось `Apple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `@ElementCollection` + `@Embeddable`, как описано в [документации](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-value):

```
@Entity
class Fruits {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();

    // геттеры и сеттеры
}

@Embeddable
class Apple {

    private String variety;

    // геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Это создаст дополнительную таблицу `Fruits_apples` с двумя полями `fruits_id` и `variety`.